# Calling function before main in static libraries

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-libraries, static-initialization

I have a type registration system for a custom form of runtime type information. Up until now I've used the following macro to call a registration function before main and register the types:

```
#define REGISTRATION                                    \
static void _register();                                \
namespace { struct temp { temp() { _register(); } }; }  \
static const temp CAT(temp, __LINE__);                  \
static void _register()
```

That way I can do this in lots of different cpp files:

```
REGISTRATION()
{
    RegisterNewType(vec2)
    ->RegisterMember("x", &vec2::x)
    ->RegisterMember("y", &vec2::y);
}
```

This works great. However this falls apart when I try and do this in a static library. It appears that this because C++ does not initialize static variables in static libraries.

I went googling for a solution and found this:

```
#define REGISTRATION                                  \
static void _register() __attribute__((constructor)); \
static void _register()
```

Which might solve my problem, but it turns out that I can only do that in clang and gcc. I am using msvc.

Is there a way to get this to work so I can have pre-main functions in libraries?

**EDIT:** Some more googling brought me to this:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#pragma section(".CRT$XCU",read)
#define EXT_REGISTRATION_(f,p) \
        static void __cdecl f(void); \
        __declspec(allocate(".CRT$XCU")) void (__cdecl*f##_)(void) = f; \
        __pragma(comment(linker,"/include:" p #f "_")) \
        static void __cdecl f(void)
#ifdef _WIN64
#define EXT_REGISTRATION(f) EXT_REGISTRATION_(f,"")
#else
#define EXT_REGISTRATION(f) EXT_REGISTRATION_(f,"_")
#endif
#else
#define EXT_REGISTRATION(f) \
        static void f(void) __attribute__((constructor)); \
        static void f(void)
#endif
```

However the registration function is still not called. The debugger states that `No symbols have been loaded`.

Comment: C++ does initialize static variables in shared libraries. Are you sure it's not a static library?

Comment: Ah yes it is a static library. I'll edit

Comment: If you have a static library, then the problem is that the symbol is not integrated in your application.

Comment: _"However it doesn't seem to work, and I don't know why."_ Can you elaborate more about the _doesn't work_ point please. _"Doesn't work"_ is a pretty poor problem description.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher this is a good point. I missed this, you also need to use it. I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this in a game engine called [Ethereal](https://github.com/volcoma/EtherealEngine). Credit goes to that guy for this code.

Instead of having the one register function I have two:

```
#define CAT_IMPL(a, b) a##b
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_IMPL(a, b)

#define REGISTER_EXTERN(cls)\
    template <typename T>\
    extern void register_func();\
    template <>\
    void register_func<cls>();\
    static const int CAT(temp, __LINE__) =\
        reg_helper::call<cls>(&register_func<cls>)

#define REGISTER(cls)\
    template <> \
    void register_func<cls>()
```

And then I have this helper function:

```
namespace reg_helper
{
    template <typename T>
    inline int call(void(*f)())
    {
        static const int s = [&f]() {
            f();
            return 0;
        }();
        return s;
    }
}
```

In header functions I define `REGISTER_EXTERN(SomeClass);`, and then in a cpp filesomewhere I use the register macro like before:

```
REGISTER(SomeClass)
{
    // This code will run before main
}
```

If you make a header file that lists all your `REGISTER_EXTERN` calls you can actually specify the order in which the the register functions will be run, since the first time the static is hit, it'll initialize and call the function. The helper ensures that the `REGISTER` function is only called once, since including the header in different places will re-initialize the static variable in each translation unit.

This solves the problem of static libraries, since the headers will be included and the symbols will exist. And secondly it ensures I can initialize things in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

As you have a static library, the problem is that by default, only the required symbols will be linked into your executable or library. By definition, these won't be your register static objects.

On Linux, use `--whole-archive` to tell gcc (or clang) to integrate the full library in the final output file.

On Windows, use `/WHOLEARCHIVE`.

The other option is to reference these objects from somewhere in your executable/shared library to force their integration.

So two options:

- whole archive, easy, but integrates everything from the static library
- manually reference the register functions inside say `main` (just having `object;` will be enough)

Comment: That might have a very detrimental effect of getting unnecessary symbols pulled in, which triggers code bloat.

Comment: Oh yes, most definitely.

Comment: @SergeyA Adding a mention to tell that's it's the easy way, the longer way being referencing all of them explicitly.

Comment: To manually refer to each registration function would be tricky and defeat the purpose of using `static`s to perform registration in the first place. At that point you might as well just call the register functions directly in `main`.

Comment: That's why each time I use plugin-like mechanisms like that, I always use a shared library.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yea I was trying to avoid just that case. I'd like the convienence of not having to do that. I just tried WHOLEARCHIVE and it fails because of duplicate symbols in other parts of the project. So I guess that's out.

Comment: Maybe the duplicate symbols should be in another library is "accessed" by this static library and the executable?

Comment: Since "normal" static library linking takes care of discarding unneeded symbols and choosing between duplicate ones, can you use whole archive linking with one or more minimal static libraries that contain your registrations and little more, and have them depend on static libraries with normal linking that contain all potentially duplicate symbols and most potentially unneeded ones?